What's the average flight distance on a typical single engine aircraft?
Statistically what is the average distance traveled per flight by a typical single engine aircraft. Since there are many types and sizes of single engine, ideally I want to limit this to small single engine aircraft like the Cessna 172.
In other words, aircraft with this conditions:
-Single engine
-Unpressurized
-4 seats max
NOTE: The average must be from flights from point A to point B only, in other words, for example flights for training in the airport pattern should be discarded.

Nobody keeps statistics on stuff like this.

Can it be estimated from something like flightaware.com logs, at least for ADS-B equipped airplanes?  Exclude flights that are too high or longer than a Cessna's range.

Average will be such a meaningless metric. The flights by a school aircraft will vary considerably from the regular tourer/commuter.

Considering the high fraction of single engine aircraft used for training, the median distance of all their flights is probably 0.00 miles - landed at the same place they departed. Once you start adding conditions, this becomes a request for somebody to run a database query (on a database of unknown existence, completeness, or quality) for you with a bunch of parameters you've specified. Not sure I see much value in such requests.

@CamilleGoudeseune how can I do that?

@Gabe I don't know how to get such data.  Even if that's hard, I still guess that there's no easier or more accurate way.  Also, as others have noted, such flights represent distinct populations that shouldn't be lumped together.  Try to define a subset, e.g. $100 hamburger run.

You'd have to do a pilot survey of cross country flights and calculate an average from the results. I'd guess about 100 miles would be a broad average, if you figure most cross country legs are 30 minutes to 2 hours.

Thanks @JohnK, I think the 30 minutes/2 hour leg input could be useful to do a simple estimation on distance. I also think the data is already there as Camille said, is just a matter of filtering, and now that you mention time I noticed FlightAware also tells you the time from takeoff to landing and also the total distance when you click on the aircraft icon. So, the data is already there all I want is to filter by single engines(which they have the ICAO type code and can be used to tell you if is single engine).

@RalphJ median won't be 0 for distance. Displacement median might be 0 but distance median cannot be 0 without negative numbers in the range.

@AadirajAnil What's the median of the following sequence: 0, 0, 0, 0, 50, 200, 500? You don't need negative values in the sequence for the median value to be zero.

Yeah but distance won't be 0 right? So where will the zeroes in that sequence come from? If an object moves, it can't travel zero distance because the actual length it travels can't be zero.

@FredLarson per flight. I've updated the post description.

https://www.reddit.com/r/flying/comments/vlj58b/whats_your_average_flight_distance/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web3x&utm_name=web3xcss&utm_term=1&utm_content=share_button
anyone saw this?

@Gabe  -   and everybody....  so basically what we are saying, here, is that given everything else, YMMV...  Perusing Aadiraj Anil's reddit link, most of those folks seem to be discussing long trips of generally several hundred miles...

507 miles is the mathification of JPE61's reference with a boatload of implied assumptions:
3.5m - General aviation and part 135 total landings single piston engine fixed wing 1-3 seats.
13m - General aviation and part 135 hours of use single piston engine fixed wing 1-3 seats.
3.7 - Hours per landing
137 - Average mph of single engine aircraft
Thus: 507 - Average miles traveled per landing

Over 3 hours per landing on average sounds extremely high, even discarding pattern work in trainers. The maximum endurance for a lot of single engine aircraft isn't much higher than that, and for every 30-minute flight, you'd need a 6+ hour flight to balance that out to get the 3.7 hours number.  And those would be rare, compared to how often the planes would have the much shorter hops. (After all, if you need to travel 500+ miles, doing so at ~137 mph isn't the most pleasant way to get there.) I'd suspect something leading to that 3.7 hours value is way off-kilter.

Thanks @RalphJ for your comment, I was going to say the same thing, but as OP I didn't wanted to sound like I'm being a pain in the *.  I think essentially the data source used  for the answer is not the most ideal for my question. As I said in the comments at the OP, the data is already there on flightaware (it tells you the distance and the time flown whether it was VFR or IFR flight) or other similar websites. All is needed is to filter by single engine(which can be determined by the ICAO type designator, which is also in the data) and aircraft takeoff and landing point (also in the data).

@RalphJ pretty much what my Stetson-Harrison indicated, and hence I didn't want to calculate any further. I do think that given the situation, Camille's approximation is very good.

@RalphJ That is what the data said. You claim that it is way off but don't have anything more than opinion for support, so let's see some data.

"That is what the data said."  But you also said:  "with a boatload of implied assumptions"  So what are the assumptions?

@MichaelHall I'm not sure I understand the point of your comment. This is a simplistic calculation based on survey data, do you not think assumptions are required? The time and landing data is 6770 opinions of pilots who fly these aircraft. Ralph said this was all wrong, that is one opinion, so I thought he ought to support his statement. I added the speed of small aircraft and applied it to the entire operating time, which is obviously inaccurate as it does not allow for ground operations or climb. Pilots probably got time from a annual hobbs meter check, so it likely is maintenance as well.

I'm simply asking you to state the assumptions you used to come up with your answer.  Is that a fair request?

Here's a thogt -  avg flight distance 300 to 350 miles; time in flight at 137 mph = 2 to 2.5 hrs...

The average distance flown by the host of singles is going to depend on what one is doing when taking such a flight and who owns the plane.  Is this a rental plane, or is this an owner flight? If we assume a majority are likely to be owner operated, is this plane a hanger queen most of the year, or is it regularly flown? Whatever the circumstances, are we going out to lunch to get a $100 hamburger?  Or is this a business or pleasure trip to a more distant location?
Speaking from experience, the hamburger flight is usually less than 150 miles.  But if we take an estimate based on the POH noted range of the 172, at an average that may be about half the range, or about 300 to 350 miles, more or, most probably, less. Why this number?  Pilots taking such day flights are generally loathe to pay for more fuel than they will use as they do not want to leave more money in the tank than necessary. Further, if they are smart, they do not want to risk fuel exhaustion, as this will likely terminate their flight career.  If we assume this plane is flown regularly, and not subject to interminable storage, the fuel cost is not likely an issue.  But if this is a rental plane, or a plane that is stored indefinitely, then we can assume fewer flights by the same pilot, and a pilot-average flight distance about half the range, more or most likely less.
On the other hand, an executive pilot owning a single-engine piston-powered aircraft may routinely fly 400 to 600 miles on a one-way out trip.  One such pilot known to me routinely flies this way in providing services to the engineering firm having the FAA contract for airport maintenance and upgrade.  Consequently, they are almost always flying to an airport with services at which, thereupon, they may fill up. In his case, about half the range would be about 450 miles. Assuming 3/4 full for the flight home, this would leave the plane 1/4 full at the hanger to be readied for the next flight.
So this is going to depend on plane ownership, reasons for the flight, and general use of the aircraft.  Consequently, without actual data (which may be hard to acquire in a specific manner), we are left to assume an estimate.  Consequently, being left to rely on assumptions where anything seemingly unique is actually one out of probably many, our estimate being half the range is probably close to the average, more or less.  For the 172, depending on the model, that is about 300 to 350 miles.

I will leave the analysis part for you, but the best source of data is here:
https://www.faa.gov/data_research/aviation_data_statistics/general_aviation/cy2022
The average distance of A to B flights is not listed, and the category closest to your specification is SEP 1-3 seats, but I guess that would be close enough.
Best approximation for avg distance would be to calculate avg hours flown with a flight plan (IFR+VFR) by the aforementioned plane category  (that would be about 32h), and then figure out from other tables how many total operations that category of planes has and work towards number of operations/aircraft/planned flight. You should be able to get a pretty  good Fermi estimate (or better) by then taking into account avg cruising speed and substract ~30 minutes of flight time per operation for taxiin.
Sorry for not doing the math for you, but I've had a pretty sciency week already, so I'm done with braining right now.
You can post your results here as an answer for peer reviewing.
Please feel free to not give points to this answer, since it only reveals data source and method, not the answer itself.

We can do some back of the envelope math to work this out. Most Cessna 172s use a variation of the Lycoming O-360 four cylinder engine. Aircraft engines have to be overhauled on a regular schedule. When an engine gets overhauled, the major components are pulled out and sent to Lycoming to be tested. Some parts are replaced, others are mixed in with a pool of identical parts. When your engine is overhauled, it can be considered a "new" engine. In an ideal world, in a well-maintained aircraft, the engine can be overhauled again and again until the plane crashes or the cost of overhaul gets too high to be worthwhile. So let's consider "an engine" to be one set of parts, and when an engine is overhauled, that's a "new engine".
Lycoming's service instructions are found here: https://www.lycoming.com/sites/default/files/attachments/SI1009BE%2520TBO%2520Schedule.pdf
Specifically, the time between overhaul for an O-360 is 2000 hours.

A Cessna 172 has a cruise speed of 125 mph. For the sake of simplicity, we can simplify the life of a Cessna 172 to either moving at cruise speed or not moving at all. For the sake of the argument, I'm going to estimate a 172 spends 80% of its life at cruise speed and the rest idling on the ground (this will vary a lot based on how this particular plane is being used, but I think this is a good starting point).
2000 hours * 0.8 * 125 mph = 200,000 miles.
I think it's reasonable to say a Lycoming O-360 engine might travel about 200,000 miles between overhauls.

I am not sure but I think he is asking about the avg single flight distance of a Cessna 172.  Not the distance it covers between overhaul

I appreciate your answer Chris but my question is referring about distance per flight

If there is any information in terms of total number of overhauls done for a country/region and a known number of airframes in that region it would be possible to approximate total distance flown, though still leaves questions how many flights that is made up of.

Oh, I turned the question around in my head. "Average flight distance on a single aircraft engine". My mistake.
